# Customize bar colors on grouped bargraph ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to change the colors of the "case" bars. For example, I want the "case" bar for agegroup a to be yellow, the "case" bar for agegroup b to be blue, the "case" bar for agegroup c to be green,etc. I just want to have the colors of the "case" bars that is currently brown in my ggplot to all be different colors.

Here is the raw data:

```
data<-data.frame("agegroup" = c("a","b","c","a","b","c"), "type" = c("case","case","case","control","control","control"), "value" = c(1,2,3,2,2,2))
```

Here is the code for ggplot:

```
ggplot(data, aes( x = agegroup, y=value, fill=type)) + 
  geom_bar(
    width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.65), stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits=c(0,10), breaks=seq(from=0, to= 10, by=1)) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 0.8),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1, size=12, face="bold"), 
        axis.title.x=element_text(margin=margin(t=10,r=20,b=20,l=20),face="bold", size=12),
        legend.text=element_text(size=8)) +
  ylab("(%)")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("brown4","grey25"), name="",labels=c("case","controls",""))+
```

[Here is a photo of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3GRH.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `ggplot`'s perspective, you want the fill color to be a combination of the `type` and `agegroup` columns. We create this combination as a separate column, and then plot normally:

```
data$fill_type = with(data, ifelse(type == "case", paste(type, agegroup), type))

ggplot(data, aes( x = agegroup, y=value, fill=fill_type)) + 
  geom_bar(
    width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.65), stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits=c(0,10), breaks=seq(from=0, to= 10, by=1)) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 0.8),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1, size=12, face="bold"), 
        axis.title.x=element_text(margin=margin(t=10,r=20,b=20,l=20),face="bold", size=12),
        legend.text=element_text(size=8)) +
  ylab("(%)")#+
  #scale_fill_manual(values = c("brown4","grey25"), name="",labels=c("case","controls",""))
```

[image]